# Notify using postgresql intervals

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3

Say, like I have a table `videoplan`:

```
create table video_plan(
id integer,
startdate timestamp,
enddate timestamp)
```

So I'm having startdate: 01.02.2022, enddate: 28.02.2022

Here, I need to show a notification like 'Renew Plan' 1 week before the enddate. How to get that in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.1 and 9.3 are [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0):

The database won't notify you. You have to query regularly with something like

```
SELECT ...
FROM video_plan
WHERE enddate < current_timestamp + INTERVAL '1 week';
```